# Animate Div Height on change Inner Html : Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a div with some content. I have placed the content inside the div using innerHtml property binding.

I also have a pipe for restricting characters and a read more button. On clicking read more button showing the full text inside the div. Upto this point it is fine, but when full text is showing the height animation is not smooth.

**Question:**
How can I make the animation smooth when full text is showing in the div? Also when the div is expanding it is expanding from bottom to top. How can I make it expand to bottom only?

**Component.html**

```html
<div
  class="text-content"
  [innerHTML]="text | summary : 150 : isCollapsed"
></div>
<div *ngIf="!isCollapsed">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
    >read more</a
  >
</div>
```

**Compoenent.css**

```css
.text-content {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #9597a8;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Pipe**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "summary",
})
export class SummaryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, length: number, isCollapsed?: boolean): any {
    if (isCollapsed) {
      return value;
    } else {
      //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English
      const biggestWord = 50;
      const elipses = "...";

      if (typeof value === "undefined") return value;
      if (value.length <= length) return value;

      //.. truncate to about correct lenght
      let truncatedText = value.slice(0, length + biggestWord);

      //.. now nibble ends till correct length
      while (truncatedText.length > length - elipses.length) {
        let lastSpace = truncatedText.lastIndexOf(" ");

        if (lastSpace === -1) break;

        truncatedText = truncatedText
          .slice(0, lastSpace)
          .replace(/[!,.?]$/, "");
      }

      return truncatedText + elipses;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try playing with overflow: hidden or use this css only: 

https://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF